# Random numbers (the number 2 or 4) in java

Tags: java

I want to randomly select either 2 or 4, with 2 having probability 0.9, and 4 having probability 0.1. How do I do this?

Comment: That's decidedly not random... <br/>
Show what you've done, we're not your homework service.

Comment: @jwenting why it's not random? Would you be able to predict what number is generated each time? I doubt that. It's just a bit different since OP wants number to be generated NOT in uniform distribution (like `Math.Random()`) and the number 2 will appear more often.

Comment: It's not random in that neither the number produced nor the frequency distribution is random. There's a 90% chance of getting 2, and a 10% chance of getting 4.

Comment: @jwenting Well if understood correctly according to wiki it is random http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness the example of bowl with 100 marbles, 90 red and 10 blue.

Comment: @Templar That's a classic example of how mathematics is taught wrong. After the first marble is drawn, the percentages have changed, and that's generally glossed over in the math classes where it's used. It's not random, it's probability calculus. Different fields (though often confused).

Comment: @jwenting well maybe not the best example I should have outlined this sentence `"That is, if the selection process is such that each member of a population, of say research subjects, has the same probability of being chosen then we can say the selection process is random".` As I understood it implies that if you take the ball and put it back in the marble then the probabilities won't change and the process will be random, same as in this question?

Comment: You can use a formula which has this pattern.

    `int twoOrFour = (int) (Math.random() / 0.9) * 2 + 2;`

This has a 90% chance of being 2 and 10% chance of being 4.

A faster alternative is to use nextInt()

    `int twoOrFour = rand.nextInt(10) / 9 * 2 + 2;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `Math.random()` or `java.util.Random` to calculate the random.

If you need a better, secured distribution than use `SecureRandom`.

Example:

```
public int randomFunc()
{
  return Math.random() > 0.1 ? 2 : 4;
}
```

or

```
public int randomFunc()
{
  final Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  int chance = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
  return chance > 0 ? 2 : 4;
}
```

What this does is:

- calculate a random number between 0(inclusiv) and 1(exclusive)
- if the number is between 0 and 0.1(exclusive) than it is a 4
- else it is a 2

The second one does it with integers:

- calculate a random integer between 0 and 9
- if the number is 0 then return 4
- else return 2

Comment: Unnecessary multiplication by 100

Comment: I would strongly recommend using `java.util.Random` (or `SecureRandom`) instead of `Math.random()`

Comment: Thank you. I was advice in a different question to use `Math.random` instead of `java.util.Random`. But for this question `SecureRandom` i think is overkill.

Answer (score 4):

random between `1` to `10` and if you got `1`, choose `4`. else, choose `2`

Comment: Or random between [1, 10] and choose 4, if you get 1

Comment: yeah2 i'll change it to the simplest one

Answer (score 4):

Start with [`Math.random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29)

> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. Returned values are chosen pseudorandomly with (approximately) uniform distribution from that range.

Using this information, you should be able to devise a simple `if-else` statement...

```
int result = 2;
double value = Math.random();
if (value < 0.1) {
    result = 4;
}
```

For example...

Answer (score 0):

The below function will achieve what you want.

```
public int GetRandom()
{
    double random = Math.random() * 100 + 1;
    int num = (int)random;

    if(num <= 10)
        return 4;

    return 2;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Fix it.

Comment: sorry, the closing braces were incorrect